# JMeter shows more memory usage than Windows performance monitor

Tags: performance, memory, jmeter, perfmon, performance-monitor

Hi I've been using JMeter PerfMon to get CPU and memory statistics. However In a previous test I decided to get help from admins and use the Windows Performance Monitor. I grabbed a sample for memory performance and it seems that PerfMon plugin tends to show an increased usage than the windows monitor:

The Windows Monitor shows a steady 50% average in the graph (and in the scv):

[image: Windows Monitor]

But the PerfMon plugin for Jmeter shows a 70% average:

[image: PerfMon]

The problem is that I don't know which results to report. I even double checked that I was targeting the right server, time range and measurement to avoid mistakes, but I don't know why each tool shows the results a bit different. The pattern is the same for other servers and indicators: higher average in Jmeter.

I'd rather use JMeter since its easier to have it setup in all of the servers and collect the results, but I don't know if those are more reliable than the ones from the windows performance monitor. In other examples around the web I saw Jmeter reports that go over 100%, so probably JMeter is already overreacting the results. Anyone knows if JMeter PerfMon are accurate enough to report it instead of the windows performance monitor? This could affect us if we set up a base line in which it could be breached in a JMeter report, but not in a Windows Monitor. Maybe someone out there compared the results of different tools.

Comment: Are you sure that it is measuring the same thing? The flat line of memory makes sense as usually the memory activity can only be seen within the JVM that the application runs in. The JVM reserves a set amount of memory, which explains the flat line. 

So in short, it looks like the windows monitor shows the actual memory used on the physical/virtual machine. While your jmeter plugin shows the JVM memory usage.

Comment: Well yes, I'm sure that I was measuring the same thing, thats why I said I double checked evrything... so in this case, windows monitor shows all memory usage from the machine, but jmeter shows only the memory usage asigned to the JVM, right?

Comment: Thats what could explain the difference you are seeing

Comment: If this is true, then its better to report the windows monitor results? since it shows the whole cpu and memory usage (im guessing i'd be having the same problem with cpu usage) ......or JVM memory usage? since I should only care about the memory asigned to the JVM

Comment: As the memory assigned to the JVM is constant, it is more interesting to look at the Jvm memory usage. Just a straight line does not give much information.

Comment: does this apply also for CPU?

Comment: Is there a way to get actual memory utilization rather than JVM using jmeter?

Comment: Late to the party but I believe that the answer you are looking for is monitoring JVM heap usage which can be done using JMX via PerfMon.